# Why aren't picklist fields created using metadata.services?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

List<MetadataService.CustomField> customFieldList = new List<MetadataService.CustomField>();
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestPicklistField__c';
customField.label = 'TestPicklistField';
customField.type_x = 'Picklist';

MetadataService.ValueSet vs = new MetadataService.ValueSet();
MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition vd = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

List<MetadataService.CustomValue> customValues = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
MetadataService.CustomValue cv1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv1.label = 'One';
cv1.fullName = 'One';
cv1.isActive = true;
cv1.default_x = false;
customValues.add(cv1);

vd.value = customValues;
vd.sorted = true;

vs.valueSetDefinition = vd;

// Use valueSet instead of Picklist
customField.valueSet  = vs;

customFieldList.add(customField);

MetadataService.SaveResult[] saveResults = service.createMetadata(customFieldList);
for(MetadataService.SaveResult saveResult : saveResults) handleSaveResults(saveResult);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Do you get an error? Does the object in question have record types? The more information you can provide, the better we can help you. Please take a moment to read about [ask], take our quick [tour], then [edit] your question to include any information you may have.